# PrimeNG Angular Take out the border of TabMenu Selected

Tags: angular, primeng

I need to take out the border of TabMenu in PrimeNG when it is selected one tab.

[image]

I am using the latest version or PrimeNG and angular 11.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Fount the solution:

```
.p-tabmenu .p-tabmenu-nav .p-tabmenuitem .p-menuitem-link:not(.p-disabled):focus {
  box-shadow: unset !important;
}
```